# Html report link isn't appearing in dashboard

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, html-reports-jenkins

[image]I have an HTMl report that needs to be viewable from the Jenkins dashboard. The report is getting archived successfully as indicated in the console output though. My script looks like:

```
      post {
            always {
                archiveArtifacts '**/target/*.tar.gz'

                publishHTML([allowMissing: false,
                             alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
                             keepAll: false,
                             reportDir: 'target',
                             reportFiles: 'dependency-check-report.html',
                             reportName: 'OWASP Dependency Check Report',
                             reportTitles: ''
                ])
            }
```

Comment: can you please add the logs also.

Comment: Please validate whether the plugin uses the correct filepath to the HTML-file. Furthermore I would try to add a value for reportTitles (even if it is named as an optional parameter).